# Itertools permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a list say x=[1,2,3,4,5] and want to look at different permutations of this list taken two number at a time.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5] 
from itertools import permutations
y=list(i for i in permutations(x,2) if i[0]<i[1])
print(y)
```

output: `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]`

But i also want `[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]` in the output.How to rectify this?

Comment: I hope you can add them yourself, can't you?

Comment: Don't use `list(<genexpr>)`. Just use a list comprehension (replace the `list(...)` with `[...]`).

Comment: @Miraj50 This is just a part of the question.There can be any number of values in the list

Comment: Yes, so after that do `y.extend([(i,i) for i in x])`.

Comment: So you want to have combinations with repeats? Is it that you want unique sets of the product of `x`, really?

Comment: what about `list(i for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(x,2) if i[0]<=i[1])`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: you don't need the `if` filter at all; for an increasing series `x`, there won't be any other tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) instead:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> list(combinations_with_replacement(x, 2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5)]
```